# Software activation solution

Tags: software-development

I am writing a piece of software. Anyone can install it for free, and it is the full product but has limited functionality.

If someone purchases the software, I want to allow the user to enter a software key and access the features. Later, I may want to provide leveled access to features (for example, if you pay $99, you get xx features, but if you pay $199, you get xx+yy features).

Preferably, it is integrated with Wordpress + WooCommerce. I see WooCommerce offers a plugin on their site but should I move off the platform, I would still like to have a licensing manager.

Can you recommend a good solution that will not break the bank?

In case this matters, my application is a Microsoft Office add-in using Winforms. This is *not* an app sold in the Microsoft App store.

Comment: Here's an option:  treat "moving off the Wordpress/WooCommerce platform" as a problem for someday and just use the WooCommerce plugin now.  Your problems are solved and you can concentrate on making your product stable and salable, and selling it.

Comment: I'm with OP.  "Beware what you build... it will last a lot longer than you think".

Comment: I have been playing around with WooCommerce and the product's APIs are really horrible. I have yet to be able to figure out how to successfully use it. Is there an inexpensive product you can recommend that can do basic licensing management? My software product is written in C#. Thanks.